# Save matrix/neo field value programmatically only for one site/locale

Tags: localization, migration, plugin-neo

During the sample content migration I save programmatically the matrix/neo field value in entry using `saveElement` method. In field settings is set "Only save blocks to the site they were created in". In the setting of each field block is set under "Entry condition" - site > is one of > correct locale.

So I expect that the field block value is saved only for locale that is set in the settings of the block. It shows/hides the blocks correctly in Control Panel for each locale, but it saves the field block values for all locales, when I save the field value programmatically. Then, in twig templates I have loops for matrix/neo blocks, where I dynamically render all the available blocks on the current page, based on the handle of the block. Here I expect that some blocks are not available on some locales, but they are there.

I've also tried to save an entry separately for each locale:

```
$entry = new Entry();
$entry->setFieldValues($sampleData);
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($entry);

$entry = Entry::find()->section('...')->slug('...')->one(); // here previous entry is found
$entry->siteId = 2;
$entry->setFieldValues($anotherSampleData);
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($entry, true, false);
```

But it throughs an error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

So maybe I'm doing something wrong? How would you separate different fields/neo field blocks for different locales, and how would you automatically fill the sample content for different locales? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the solution is found.
In Channel Setting is: `Save entries to all sites enabled for this section`.
In Neo Field Settings: `Only save blocks to the site the were created in`.

```
$entry = new Entry();
$entry->setFieldValues($sampleData);
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($entry);

// here find previous entry and filter only for needed siteId, add different field values and save the entry again
$entry = Entry::find()->section('...')->slug('...')->siteId(2)->one(); 
$entry->setFieldValues($anotherSampleData);
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($entry);
```